# ssh into Google Compute Engine without gcloud -> Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud, public-key-encryption

I need to ssh into my Google Compute Engine instance (GCE) without using gloud compute ssh. gcloud works for me but I want to use ssh & sshfs to mount my GCE file system running Ubuntu 18 to my Mac.

I ran ssh-keygen on the GCE instance, which asked for a passphrase which I entered, producing new.key and new.key.pub.

I've copied both these files into my local Mac computer at ~/user/ and ~/.ssh/ and given them 777 permissions.

However, ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx still doesn't work => Permission denied (publickey).

I don't seem to have a file called ~/.ssh/authorized_keys if that's a matter.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: If you have previously run `gcloud compute ssh` then you will find the keypair to use in your home directory as `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`. You will need to enable ssh command debugging to figure out exactly what causes permission denied which could be many things from wrong key to wrong file permission on the key pair. I would throw away the keys that you used. Start over with `gcloud` and use the keypair that `gcloud` created. This is the simplest method.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I reinitiated gcloud compute update, init, logged into my account, and then gcloud config sshkey.

Comment: My actual commands were: gcloud components update, gcloud init, gcloud compute config-ssh